Find all positive integer triples $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^4+y^4=z^3+215z+1$
Find all positive integer triples $(x,y,z)$
such that $x^4+y^4=z^3+215z+1$
My Attempt
I began by analyzing the given equation:
$$x^4 + y^4 = z^3 + 215z + 1.$$
Here, $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, and I am   trying to find solutions where the sum of two fourth powers equals a cubic polynomial in $z$. To proceed, I  analyzed both sides and applied modular arithmetic to restrict possible values for $x$, $y$, and $z$.
Since the terms involve powers and $z^3 + 215z + 1$ includes $z$ raised to the third power, a good starting point is checking the equation modulo small integers to see if any congruences help eliminate certain possibilities.
I started by reducing the equation modulo 3.

The fourth powers of integers modulo 3 have a predictable pattern:

$0^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$,
$1^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$,
$2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

So, for any $x$ and $y$, we have:
$$x^4 + y^4 \equiv 0, 1, \text{or } 2 \pmod{3}.$$

Now for the right-hand side, $z^3 + 215z + 1 \mod 3$:

$z^3 \equiv z \pmod{3}$ (since $z^3 \mod 3$ gives the same result as $z \mod 3$).
$215z \equiv z \pmod{3}$ (because $215 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$).

Thus, $z^3 + 215z + 1 \equiv z + z + 1 = 2z + 1 \pmod{3}$.


So, the equation modulo 3 becomes:
$$ x^4 + y^4 \equiv 2z + 1 \pmod{3}. $$
Now i checked the possible values:

If $x^4 + y^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, then $2z + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow z \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.
If $x^4 + y^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, then $2z + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow z \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.
If $x^4 + y^4 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, then $2z + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \Rightarrow z \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Thus, modulo 3 allows  to narrow down the possible values of $z$. Next,  checked modulo 5.
The fourth powers modulo 5 also have a simple cycle:

$0^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$,
$1^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$,
$2^4 \equiv 16 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$,
$3^4 \equiv 81 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$,
$4^4 \equiv 256 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Thus:
$$x^4 + y^4 \equiv 0, 1, 2 \pmod{5}.$$
For $z^3 + 215z + 1 \pmod{5}$:

$z^3 \pmod{5}$ cycles with $z$:

$z = 0 \Rightarrow z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$,
$z = 1 \Rightarrow z^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$,
$z = 2 \Rightarrow $ (similar cyclical behavior),
The same applies to $215z \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.



Thus the right-hand side behaves similarly, and the congruences narrow down.
Then I Analyzed possible $x, y, z$ for small values.
Now that we have congruences, I checked small possible values of $x$, $y$, and $z$,  systematically, but I think it's unlikely
for integer solutions to arise.
I am stucked at this point.Can anyone help me in this question I have tried a lot to find triples satisfying this condition but till now I have not found any.

$215\equiv2\bmod3$.

$z^3+215z+1\equiv 1\bmod 3$ for all $z$.

$(x,y,z)=(6,7,11)$

Yes I was able to find that solution by executing a python code it turns out that between 1 to 1000 only this permutation satisfies the equation. I think this is the only solution. But how can we give a rigorous proof of this fact

What is the source of this question? The answer will depend on this. If it is a random Diophantine equation, chances are not good to find a complete solution. If it is from a competition, then other people have thought about it, and it makes sense.

If they have any other Solutions then $X=2p$, $Y=2q +1$ & $Z=2r $ or $ 2r+1$

@Guruprasad: It is obvious that $RHS$ is always odd whatever be the parity of $z$ and for this, $x$ and $y$ should be of distinct parity.
